# When to use <strong>, <em> or <mark>?

Tags: html

Sorry if this is sounding fussy but I'm about to produce a whole lot of HTML 5 and I was hoping someone out there had come up with some clear rules for when to use the <em>, <strong> and <mark> tags. The spec suggests some subtle differences but I keep finding myself asking whether I want the text bolded, italic or yellow high-lighted, which makes me think I should be using CSS instead. (And sometimes I wonder why I even bother when I could just as easily write "Cats are NOT dogs.")

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> I keep finding myself asking whether I want the text bolded, italic or yellow high-lighted, which makes me think I should be using CSS instead.

That's 100% correct. Markup is for describing content, not appearance. That being said:

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html

- The `<strong>` element represents strong importance for its contents. Changing the importance of a piece of text with **the strong element does not change the meaning of the sentence**.
- The `<em>` element represents stress emphasis of its contents. The placement of stress emphasis **changes the meaning of the sentence**.
- The `<mark>` element represents a run of text in one document marked or highlighted for reference purposes, **due to its relevance in another context**.

`<mark>` doesn't really have relevance to content, only context (e.g. marking content that matches a search term, misspelled words, selected content in a web app, etc.).

`<strong>` denotes important text, but does *not* affect meaning.

`<em>` denotes important text and affects the meaning of the content by saying that it should be read/spoken with emphasis.

You are free to use CSS to change browser defaults for all of these elements.

Comment: Hi thanks. This is a good summary of the spec, but its the search item example for "mark" that has really helped me. Now that I think of it I've seen this used before. If I keep "mark" just for this sort of thing, then the "strong" vs. "em" question gets a lot easier.

Comment: A lot of HTML tag choice is up for debate, the best you can do is follow the spec as much as you can and be consistent. Don't be afraid to use something like `<em class="highlighted">` or plain old spans if it's only presentation you care about.

Answer (score 3):

Remember HTML is a markup language. Inside it you write the content of the page. If you use "Cats are NOT dogs", search engines like google don't know whether "DOGS" is a distinguished phrase or not (of course your readers will notice it, though). If you use CSS, which is a styling language, same thing happens: search engines don't recognize "DOGS" as distinguished text but users do.

When you use the elements of your question, they indeed give information. They're called semantic elements. For example it's more informative for the search engine (or screen reader or speaking software) to use element `<h1>` for titles than just using `<p>` and through CSS making it big and bold. Another example is using `alt` and `title` attributes in `img`, 'cause engines don't understand what image you have in `src`.

So, even though any of the HTML elements `<em>`, `<strong>`, `<mark>` are noticeable for the **user**, they give different meaning to the text inside them for the **engines**.

Comment: Thanks. That is a good point. Not all readers are human (at least not all mine).

Answer (score 1):

Look for writing style for e.g. books. True, webpages are less formal than this, but it should give you a starting point. Italic text (i.e., <em>) is used for emphasis. Boldface (<strong>) is used for titles and such, very rarely in running text.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for your advice. I was worried this question is too pedantic, but there seems to have been a shift from styling to semantic definitions in HTML 5 (e.g. "small" is now fine-print) and I wanted to get my understanding clear on these. I think it was the new "mark" that was throwing me most.